nvm doesn't work in file, but work globally
I cloned a project and trying to change version of node.js via nvm. Globally, in the terminal it shows that node version is 16.20.0 (correct one), but in the project i working with its 18.20.0 and i cant change it because it shows that nvm not found. Tried to delete the node.js but seems it doesn't help...
Globally:
nvm -v
0.37.2

node -v
v16.20.0


Project:
 nvm -v
zsh: command not found: nvm

 node -v
v18.20.2


How should i change the node version and what to do to use nvm in my project file?

Are you using different shell when testing globally and in the project? Try running echo $SHELL in both cases and see what you get.

the same answer in both cases /bin/zsh

try running which node in both cases

globally is /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node
in the project is /usr/local/bin/node

The problem was in webstorm, it couldn't detect nvm. I add source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh in .zshrc file and set the right path in settings (webstorm - settings - languages & frameworks - node.js - node interpreter).
It took all my day :(
